# Django model not Associating with another model object

Tags: django

I am using Django to create an application where I have an Employee model that needs to be associated with a Company model. I am able to associate the User model with the Employee model correctly, but I am having trouble associating the Company object with the Employee object.

My view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from company.models import Company
from .models import Employee
from .forms import UserForm, CompanyForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import random, string
from django.db import IntegrityError


def new(request):    
    # Initialize forms
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    company_form = CompanyForm(request.POST or None)

    # Check if the request is a POST request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Check if both forms are valid
        if user_form.is_valid() and company_form.is_valid():
            email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']

            # Check if a user with this email already exists
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                user_created = False
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User(username=email, email=email)
                random_password = User.objects.make_random_password()
                user.set_password(random_password)
                user.save()
                user_created = True

            # Save the company form data
            company = company_form.save()

            # Check if an Employee already exists for this user
            try:
                employee = Employee.objects.get(user=user)
                employee_created = False
            except Employee.DoesNotExist:
                employee = Employee(user=user, company=company)
                employee.save()
                employee_created = True

            # Return appropriate response based on what was created
            if user_created:
                return HttpResponse('User and Employee created with password: ' + random_password)
            elif employee_created:
                return HttpResponse('Employee created for existing user.')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('User with that username already exists. Please try again.')

    user_form = UserForm()
    company_form = CompanyForm()

    # Render the page with the forms
    return render(request, 'new_business.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'company_form': company_form})
```

My Employee model:

```
from django.db import models
from company.models import Company
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from varvocrm.models import BaseModel

# Create your models here.
class Employee(models.Model):    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    @property
    def is_deleted(self):
        return self.deleted_at is not None
    
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active and not self.is_deleted
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username if self.user else ''
```

My Company model:

```
from django.db import models
from varvocrm.models import BaseModel

# Create your models here.
class Company(models.Model):
    
    countries = [
        ('Norway', 'Norway'),
        ('Sweden', 'Sweden'),
        ('Denmark', 'Denmark'),
    ]
    
    organization_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Norway', choices=countries)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.organization_number
    
class Settings(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logo/', blank=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='NOK')
    tax = models.IntegerField(default=25)
    option_accept_offers = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    option_price_include_tax = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    option_send_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    option_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    option_locked_message = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='Locked by admin, contact customer service for more information.')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company.name if self.company else ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not associating a company with an existing employee. This may be intentional, but if there's existing employees not linked to a company, they'll stay that way in the above example. I'd also adjust the way you create the employee a little.

You could do something like;

```
            # Save the company form data
            company = company_form.save()

            # Check if an Employee already exists for this user
            try:
                employee = Employee.objects.get(user=user)
                if employee.company != company:
                    employee.company = company
                    employee.save(update_fields=['company'])
                employee_created = False
            except Employee.DoesNotExist:
                employee = Employee.objects.create(user=user, company=company)
                employee_created = True
```

Or even simpler;

```
employee, employee_created = Employee.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

if employee.company != company:
    employee.company = company
    employee.save(update_fields=['company'])
```

Comment: Yeah, you are correct! Thank you so much for pointing that out!